# dynamodb table index design gloabl index or local

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have 3 dynamodb tables, like:

```
  companies:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: ${self:provider.region}.${opt:stage}.companies
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: ${self:provider.region}.${opt:stage}.${self:custom.customDomain.domainName}
  addresses:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: ${self:provider.region}.${opt:stage}.addresses
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: ${self:provider.region}.${opt:stage}.${self:custom.customDomain.domainName}
  users:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    DependsOn: companies
    Properties:
      TableName: ${self:provider.region}.${opt:stage}.users
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: email
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: upload_id
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: company
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: email
          KeyType: RANGE
      LocalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: LSI-${self:provider.region}-${opt:stage}-companyId-by-userId-index
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: company
              KeyType: HASH
            - AttributeName: id
              KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: ALL
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: GSI-${self:provider.region}-${opt:stage}-uploadId-by-userId-index
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: upload_id
              KeyType: HASH
            - AttributeName: id
              KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: ALL
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: ${self:provider.region}.${opt:stage}.${self:custom.customDomain.domainName}
```

basically a company record would have many address and a user will belong to only one company, this user was uploaded using a unique upload_id that could have uploaded many users, so:

if i want to get all the users who have a specific `upload_id`, is a Global Index better?

and if i want to get all users from one company, would a Local Secondary Index better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use a Local Secondary Index (LSI) if you require the index to be strongly consistent. If you are okay with an eventually consistent index, then you should use a Global Secondary Index (GSI) because LSIs have a lot of limitations.

- LSIs cannot be modified or deleted without deleting and recreating the whole table. GSIs can be created/removed at any time with no impact to the main table.
- LSIs cause you to have a limit of 10 GB of data per *partition key*. Without a LSI, there is a limit of 10 GB per partition, but you won’t notice that because DynamoDB can split your data for a single partition key across multiple partitions if necessary.
- When using a LSI, the 400kb item size limit applies to the item plus all of its LSI projections. An item in a GSI is counted separately from the item in the main table.
- Provisioned capacity of GSIs can be scaled independently of the main table, whereas LSIs share the same capacity as the base table.

See [Improving Data Access with Secondary Indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) for more details.